# c# using BackgroundWorker while scan directores and its subfolders

Tags: c#, directory, backgroundworker

I have this simple code in c# which find all targeted directory and its sub_folders   which is working but i while its processing i cant interactive with the GUI form i red that i should use BackgroundWorker how to implemented with this code:

```
  var dir = textBox1.Text = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath; 
  textBox2.Text="";
  string[] extensions = { ".htm", ".html" };
  var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.*",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
  .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".html") || s.EndsWith(".htm")).OrderBy(f => f);

                 foreach (string file in files)
                 { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file);
                   textBox2.AppendText(file+Environment.NewLine);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this link? Pay attention to updating gui from other thread (with BackgroundWorker this is usually accomplished in ProgressChanged event handler:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8xdz5c(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: well i tried didn't work the loop wont work only once then its stop

Answer (score 0):

never-mind i found a solution :

```
    void BackgroundWorker1DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {  
          string[] extensions = { ".htm", ".html" };
          var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .Where(s => s.EndsWith(".html") || s.EndsWith(".htm")).OrderBy(f => f);


          foreach (string file in files)
           {  
            Thread.Sleep(5);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(file);
              backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0,file+Environment.NewLine);
           }


    }
    void BackgroundWorker1ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

      textBox2.AppendText(e.UserState as string);

    }
```